# Finding the sum of the lowest two values from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using two tables, I am trying to show the years where the average price from Table1(Green_Certs) is greater than the sum of the lowest two prices from Table2(Trading).  The problem is I don't know how to Sum the two lowest values from the second table.  This is my code so far.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
Select Year_Traded
From Green_Certs
Where Avg(Price)>
(Select min(Price)
     From Trading);
```

Comment: Would this be a correct re-statement of your request?  For every year on record, I want to check if the average price from `Green_Certs` for that year's records is greater than the sum of the lowest two values from `Trading` *for that year's records*. If so, @Rick James answer should still work - however, you would have to limit the rows in `Trading` based on `Green_Certs.Year_Traded` - using information we don't know about that would be in `Trading`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry if I wasn't too clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Price
    FROM Trading
    ORDER BY Price
    LIMIT 2;
```

will find the 2 lowest values.

Wrap that to get the `SUM` (or `AVG` or whatever):

```
SELECT SUM(Price) as sum_price
    FROM ( SELECT Price
            FROM Trading
            ORDER BY Price
            LIMIT 2 )
```

Then (I think) use that instead of the subquery you have.

Answer (score 0):

you hvn't explained fully.

> Per year Avg price should be greater than sum of 2 lowest price per
>   year
>
> or
>
> Per year Avg price should be greater than sum of 2 lowest price

Try something like this

```
select years,AVgPrice FROM
(
select years, avg(price) AVgPrice
from table
group by years
)t4
where AVgPrice>
(
select sum(price) Price
from
(
select top 2 price
 from table2
 order by price
 )
 )
```